# Electron Interference when produced by $W$ boson

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, interference, wave-particle-duality

Hi I was wondering about the following setup. Let’s say we have a radioactive atom which decays via beta decay which produces a $W$ boson. The $W$ boson has a chance of turning into an electron or a muon or other particles. However let’s say that the atom is surrounding by a barrier on all sides such that the radius of the barrier is smaller than the electron De Broglie wavelength of the produced electron but not smaller than the De Broglie wavelength of a produced muon. Would this impact the likelihood of an electron vs a muon being observed due to the $W$ boson decay? Would there be any weird phenomena due to electron interference patterns at such small scales?

Comment: How would you perform this experiment?

Comment: but there is no muon wavelength b/c the decay is prohibited by energy conservation. The electron has a wavelength that is around 100x smaller than the Bohr radius, so the experiment just isn't happening. Note that a Bohr radius times the fine structure constant, $a_0/137$, get down to the Compton wavelength, and to confine an electron to that size has enough momentum uncertainty to product $e^+e^-$ pairs. It's just not a physically sensible set-up.

Comment: "Decays via beta decay which produces a W boson" The beta decay W is virtual, a virtual particle has all the quantum numbers of the named particle but is **off mass shell* .  see this link for virtual particles.  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html there is a paragraph about virtual W and Z .

Answer (score 1):

This scenario goes off the rails when you say the neutron emits as $W^-$ boson. This does not represent physics, rather, it represents a term in a perturbation series in Old Fashioned Perturbation theory, and as such, does not occur in isolation. It's amplitude must be added to the vacuum creation of $W^+e^-\bar{\nu}_e$ in which the neutron absorbs the $W^+$ and becomes a proton. (I am not an expert in OFPT, so that's all I have to say about that).

The PDB (https://pdg.lbl.gov/2022/listings/contents_listings.html) doesn't list:

$$ n\rightarrow p+\mu^-+\bar\nu_{\mu}$$

so that will pose challenges. (I suspect the amplitude is non-zero, but the phase space is zero because $m_{\mu} > M_n - M_p$ by two orders of magnitude.)

Regarding slit sizes, you should really put some effort in final state energy spectra in beta decay (readily available), and use the deBrogile relation.

Finally, decay rates can be affected by external circumstances (e.g: neutron stars), see the Quantum Zeno Effect (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Zeno_effect) for more.

Comment: There are zero pairs of nuclei with the same $A$ whose mass difference is larger than the 100 MeV mass of the muon, so the neutron-to-muon decay does not occur for any free or bound neutron. I vaguely recall reading papers about muon emission in hot neutron stars, among other kinds of macroscopic-nucleus bizarreness. If you hit a neutron hard enough to excite a $\Delta$ resonance, *that* might decay by muon emission — but it's most likely to involve an intermediate charged pion.

Comment: The "non-zero amplitude" you describe might be involved in something like $\mu^-+p\to n+\nu_\mu$, which you can imagine occurring in muonic atoms, where a muon is bound to a nucleus. But that would probably be a tiny correction to the (quasi-)free decay of the muons.

Comment: @rob when I say non-zero amplitude, I mean $M$ in Fermi's Golden Rule. The density of final states is clearly zero. Regarding CC muon proton scattering....isn't there some kind of symmetry (crossing? or when you swap Mandelstam variables...) that implies my initial "suspicion" isn't totally off-base?

Comment: Yes, I think we are agreeing with each other.